# ASP.NET Queries not changing with strings and paramters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am running queries as a string that has a single parameter (and is changed) but am getting some odd behavior.  Here is the code:

```
String cmd = "SELECT RID FROM SCHEMAS 
              WHERE NAMESPACE_PREFIX = '" + prefix + "' AND GENERIC_SCHEMA = 1";

Response.Write(cmd + "<br>");

using (SqlDataReader elementReader = elementDB.executeCommand(cmd))
{
    while (elementReader.Read())
    {
        Response.Write(cmd+ elementReader["RID"].ToString() + "<br>");
    }
}
```

*What I expect to happen:*

> The `Response.Write` executes two times and the the data is identical.

*What is actually happening:*

> The elementReader appears to 'memorize' the first value of prefix. 
>   When the 'prefix' variable changes, the Response.Write outside the 
>   SQL statement is correctly outputting the string, however the while 
>   loop inside the SQL statement does not execute at all.  However,
>   whenever  'prefi'x comes back to the first value it was set to, the
>   statement DOES  execute.

I am at a complete loss as to why this is happening and would appreciate help.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the output that you *are* getting to add to the explanation of why it's not what you expect?  Also, in your example, the `prefix` variable is not being changed.  Is there additional code that has not been provided in your original example?

Comment: I hope your just writing a Select statement like that for troubleshooting

Comment: I don't see prefix variable being changed , or a spot in the while loop to check to see if it was changed , it is just going to execute reader with the variable assigned when it started reading

Comment: The most likely cause is two records in the database with the same NAMESPACE_PREFIX

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned, yes the prefix is being changed in another part of the code.  I left it out to make it easier to read. But the first Response.Write is outputting the correctly modified 'prefix.'

Comment: Steve I cant believe it was something that dumb but that was it.  Wow, thanks a lot

Comment: @Nilish, please refrain from using code blocks for purely presentational purposes.  It makes the post harder to read.

Comment: @SteveWellens I think you should post that as an answer, so he can close the question.

Comment: I reposted my comment as an answer (but left the original comment since it was referenced by other comments).

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is two records in the database with the same NAMESPACE_PREFIX.

Maybe you need a unique index on that field.